# How can I locally access my react js app with wamp and allow access to other computers?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, wamp, hosting

I created a CRUD app. Here is what I use :

- React js for the front-end
- Node.js and Express to communicate with my database
- WAMP with MySQL on it for my database (I use WAMP only to use MySQL, I don't use WAMP as a server)

I want my app to be accessible by other computers. Currently, I access my app on "http://localhost:3000". Other computers could be able to access my app thanks to my ip adress like this "http://myipadress". I saw that this was possible with WAMP, but all exemples that I found didn't use Node js. So I was wondering, as I use node js as a server, is it possible to make accessible my local react js app to other computers thanks to WAMP ? I am new to developpement so I am a bit lost.

Thank you in advance for all answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Develop React w/ full-stack (WAMP) locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278864/develop-react-w-full-stack-wamp-locally)

Answer (score 0):

with XAMPP its easy and its almost same local server

> 

1. Go to Your XAMPP Control panel
2. Click on apache > config > Apache (httpd.conf)
3. Search for Listen 80 and replace with Listen 8080
4. After that check your local ip using ipconfig command (cmd console)
5. Search for ServerName localhost:80 and replace with your local ip:8080 (ex.192.168.1.156:8080)
6. After that open apache > config > Apache (httpd-xampp.conf)
7. FIND

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
      AllowOverride AuthConfig
      **Require local**   Replace with   **Require all granted**
      ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
  </Directory>
```

8. Go to xampp > config > click on service and port setting and change apache port 8080
9. restart xampp and then hit your IP:8080 (ex.192.168.1.156:8080) from another computer